# Java generics - an object of type T isn't allowed for a method that accepts <? extends T>

Tags: java, generics

In the following example the compiler complains on the line:
handler.handle(info); with the error:

> The method handle(capture#3-of ?
>   extends T) in the type
>   Event.Handler is not applicable for the arguments
>   (T)

Even though the Handler in this case is declared to accept any subclass of T, the compiler wont accept a method call of type T itself.

```
public class Event<T> {
    public interface Handler<U> {
        public void handle(U info);
    }

    private final Handler<? extends T> handler;
    private final T info;

    public Event(Handler<? extends T> handler, T info) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.info = info;
    }

    public void doEvent() {
        handler.handle(info);
    }
}
```

Another interesting feature of this example is if you type: "handler." in eclipse the following suggestion is given "handle(null info): void". Somehow the type 'null' is being suggested as the acceptable type.

Compiling with javac from the command line still produces a similar error, so this is not just an eclipse issue.

My questions:

1. Is this the correct behavior of the java compiler?
2. If it is the correct behavior, what should I be doing to keep type safety for my event class?
3. What is a `null` type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's declared to be a Handler of some type extending T. Imagine T is Object, and you pass in a `Handler<String>`. That's fine from the point of view of the constructor - but you then wouldn't expect to be able to call `handler.handle(new Object())` would you? A `Handler<String>` should only be expected to handle strings, not arbitrary objects.

Basically you're looking for contravariance instead of covariance, so you need:

```
private final Handler<? super T> handler;
private final T info;

public Event(Handler<? super T> handler, T info) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.info = info;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'd been thinking about this backwards for so long! With a complicated hierarchy of generics it gets brain-cooking :)

Comment: @Jon According to PECS mnemonic coined Josh Bloch <? super T> should be used when the parameter is a destination . How is handler a destination in this case ?

Comment: @Geek: It's a "destination" in that it's a sink for events. It *receives* an `Event<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Answering your third question.

There are two kinds of types in java: the primitive and the reference types.
Actually null is a kind of third special type in java.

> There is also a special null type, the
>   type of the expression null, which has
>   no name. Because the null type has no
>   name, it is impossible to declare a
>   variable of the null type or to cast
>   to the null type. The null reference
>   is the only possible value of an
>   expression of null type. The null
>   reference can always be cast to any
>   reference type. In practice, the
>   programmer can ignore the null type
>   and just pretend that null is merely a
>   special literal that can be of any
>   reference type.

[source](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html)

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I'd never come across the null type before but I suppose it makes sense. I'd mark this as the answer too if I could.